# Read Excel in R

Tags: r, excel

In excel I have a table that looks like this:

```
`    Data Freq
1 [35-39]    1
2 [40-44]    3
3 [45-49]    5
4 [50-54]   11
5 [55-59]    7
6 [60-64]    7`
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of being able to read the value in the Data column as the intervals for calculations in the R Project software.

I need to calculate things as:

```
`(39-35)/2`
```

Comment: `dput(mydata)` by reading the data from excel in R

Comment: And what is the exact problem? Reading the file into R or reordering the data you have read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# read
library(xlsx)
d <- read.xlsx('data.xlsx',header=T,sheetIndex=1)
# reorder
dl <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(d$Data),split='-|\\[|\\]'))
d$b <- as.numeric(dl[,3])
d$a <- as.numeric(dl[,2])
# calculate
d$mid <- (d$b-d$a)/2+d$a
```

Comment: In case you do not have xlsx package installed, use export to CSV and read.csv function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that doesn't use libraries is to convert you excel file into a csv (via `save as` in excel) and then read the data using `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

`xlsx` uses `rJava` and needs Java. An alternative is  `readxl`

```
library(readxl)

ed=read_excel("myfile.xlsx")
```